# Geometry (ratio of subdivided length in a triangle)

Tags: geometry, triangles, ratio

In triangle ABC, label *X* on *AB* and *Y* on *AC* such that *AX : XB = CY : YA* =  2 : 1. Extend *XY* and *BC* up to  point *Z* by a length $u$ beyond $Y, YZ=u $. Find *ZB : ZC* in terms of $u$.

Comment: Can you please draw the image?

Comment: @ YIPYIP I have changed the problem statement a bit, Please change back if it is not exactly in line with what you are wanting to pose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Theorem of Menelaus:

(AX/XB)*(BZ/ZC)*(CY/YA)=1

Replace AX/XB with 2
CY/YA with 2

And you get ZB/ZC= 1/4